# Confirm close window popup does not appear on first time

Tags: javascript, browser, window, focus

I am trying following code to confirm user if they really want to close window.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
    function confirmExit() {
        return "You have attempted to leave this page. Are you sure?";
    }
</script>
```

But it does not work when my page load and I try to close page `[X]` without clicking anywhere on page. Yes it does appear when I click somewhere on page then close `[X]` window. I don't know why do I need to click somewhere on page and then close window.
What I tried so far but nothing works.

1. window.focus() on document ready as it gets focus on window.
2. $('#someElementOnpageId').click() as it gets auto click on document
       ready.

Can anyone please suggest what should I do?

Comment: That is the browser feature so doubt there is anything you can do.

Comment: from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) "Note: To combat unwanted pop-ups, some browsers don't display prompts created in beforeunload event handlers unless the page has been interacted with; some don't display them at all..."  As an aside, if a user clicked the X without otherwise interacting with the page, there's not really a reason to ask them if they want to leave.

Comment: Thanks @James, sounds good.